# Hosting a file on github (submitting a file to PyPI)

Tags: github, pypi

I'm following [this](http://peterdowns.com/posts/first-time-with-pypi.html) guide and I have everything in place but the file hosting. I'm lost here:

*The download_url is a link to a hosted file with your repository's code. Github will host this for you, but only if you create a git tag. In your repository, type: git tag 0.1 -m "Adds a tag so that we can put this on PyPI.". Then, type git tag to show a list of tags — you should see 0.1 in the list. Type git push --tags origin master to update your code on Github with the latest tag information. Github creates tarballs for download at https://github.com/{username}/{module_name}/tarball/{tag}.*

Am I supposed to clone my existing github repository to my computer using git shell?

As a beginner, I can say that coding seems to be 5x easier and 5x more fun than the fluff surrounding the actual coding :( (for fluff read installers, project skeleton directories etc)

Comment: Maybe this will bump it to where someone can see it, dumb beginner question though it is.

Answer (score 0):

```
C:\Users\Dave\Desktop\distributing> git clone https://github.com/dmt257/hellodmt2.git
Cloning into 'hellodmt2'...
remote: Counting objects: 8, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (6/6), done.
remote: Total 8 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
Unpacking objects: 100% (8/8), done.
Checking connectivity... done.
C:\Users\Dave\Desktop\distributing> git-tag 0.1 -m "adds a tag so that we can out this on PyPI."
git-tag : The term 'git-tag' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.
Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ git-tag 0.1 -m "adds a tag so that we can out this on PyPI."
+ ~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (git-tag:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

C:\Users\Dave\Desktop\distributing> ls


    Directory: C:\Users\Dave\Desktop\distributing


Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                -------------         ------ ----
d-----       23/08/2016     07:56                helloDistribution
d-----       24/08/2016     06:26                hellodmt2
d-----       23/08/2016     14:16                hellodmt2Distribution
d-----       23/08/2016     08:02                hellodmtDistribution


C:\Users\Dave\Desktop\distributing> cd .\hellodmt2
C:\Users\Dave\Desktop\distributing\hellodmt2 [master ≡]> git tag 0.1 -m "Adds a tag so that we can put this on PyPI."
C:\Users\Dave\Desktop\distributing\hellodmt2 [master ≡]> git tag
0.1
C:\Users\Dave\Desktop\distributing\hellodmt2 [master ≡]> git push --tags origin master
Counting objects: 1, done.
Writing objects: 100% (1/1), 180 bytes | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 1 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
To https://github.com/dmt257/hellodmt2.git
 * [new tag]         0.1 -> 0.1
C:\Users\Dave\Desktop\distributing\hellodmt2 [master ≡]>
```

links seem to be this format (under releases option in github account), not as shown in guide:

https://github.com/dmt257/hellodmt2/archive/0.1.tar.gz